# How to Remove Unwanted Button Shadows

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

My iOS app has had these two buttons for months now:

[image: no shadow]

They are added in IB but in the viewDidLoad I round the corners and update the background color.

Today I added a feature to a textField that's on the same view. Now when the VC loads/presents the view appears and, after a quarter second delay, shadows appear behind the buttons:

[image: shadow]

I hadn't changed a single thing in attribute inspector. Nor had I changed the code rounding the buttons. Since the problem began, I've now added explicit no-shadow code and made sure the inspector is set to clear-shadows.

```
func roundBut (Type: UIView) {
    Type.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    Type.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    Type.layer.masksToBounds = true
    Type.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    Type.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
    Type.layer.shadowColor = nil
    Type.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
}
```

The last odd thing about this is that if I click into the text-field, the shadows go away.

**More code, as requested:**

Here's pretty much every bit of code associated with this including the viewDidLoad, the corner rounding functions, and the code for the text field and text view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //If user is editing a cell, check...
    if passingEdit == true {
        //If passed an 'Add New' cell: It clears that text
        if namePassed == nil && descPassed == "Add new" {
            txtDesc.text = ""
            addSave.setTitle("Add", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            action.hidden = true
            actionsBox.hidden = true
            passingEdit = false
        }
        else {
            //Otherwise: Fill both fields with cell's content
            txtTask.text = namePassed
            txtDesc.text = descPassed
            action.hidden = true //Becasue action box will be visible
            addSave.setTitle("Update", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }
    else {
        txtTask.becomeFirstResponder()
        addSave.setTitle("Add", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        action.hidden = true
        actionsBox.hidden = true
    }

    //If user hasn't added details: Show Placeholder
    if txtDesc.text.isEmpty {
        txtDesc.text = "Tap here to add details."
        txtDesc.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    }

    //Sets editor header text
    switch (currentListEntity) {
    case "TodayTask":
        hdr_Txt.setTitle("Today", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        txtTask.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"I need to...", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor()])
        move_TopBtn.setTitle("Add to 'Tomorrow'", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        move_TopBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 49/255.0, green: 82/255.0, blue: 172/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    case "TomTask":
        hdr_Txt.setTitle("Tomorrow", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        txtTask.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"I need to...", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor()])
        move_TopBtn.setTitle("Add to 'Today'", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        move_TopBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 128/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    case "TBDTask":
        hdr_Txt.setTitle("Do Later", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        txtTask.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"At some point, I need to...", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor()])
    case "FinTask":
        //This won't likely run, as "Fin" does not have an add button
        hdr_Txt.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    default:
        //Should run when user's current location is the Life Lists
        hdr_Txt.setTitle("List Item", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        txtTask.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Name of List Item", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor()])
        move_TopBtn.setTitle("Add to 'Today'", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        move_TopBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 128/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        move_BotBtn.setTitle("Add to 'Tomorrow'", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        move_BotBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 49/255.0, green: 82/255.0, blue: 172/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }


    //Round check / delete views
    makeCircle(deleteBtn)
    makeCircle(doneBtn)
    //Round corners of rectangles
    roundBut(move_TopBtn)
    roundBut(move_BotBtn)

    move_TopBtn.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    move_TopBtn.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0

    print("editorVC viewDidLoad ran")
}//End of viewDidLoad




//*****************************
//Setup - Reference Functions
//*****************************

//Round contentView
func roundBut (Type: UIView) {
    Type.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    Type.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    Type.layer.masksToBounds = true
    Type.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    Type.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
    Type.layer.shadowColor = nil
    Type.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
}
func makeCircle (viewToRound: UIButton) {
    viewToRound.layer.cornerRadius = viewToRound.frame.size.width/2
    viewToRound.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    viewToRound.layer.masksToBounds = true
}



//***** ----- ***** ------ ***** ----- ***** ----- *****
//Functionality
//***** ----- ***** ------ ***** ----- ***** ----- *****

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if txtTask.text != "" {
        action.hidden = false
    }
}

//Dismisses keyboard upon tapping the return key
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

//Dismisses keyboard upon touch outside text boxes
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    action.hidden = true
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing (textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor() {
        textView.text = nil
        textView.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
    action.hidden = false
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
        txtDesc.text = "Tap here to add details."
        textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    }
}
```

Last note: the dark grey background is a visual effect view. Not sure if that matters.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try explicitly disabling the shadows on the textField? My thought is maybe there's some bug with masksToBounds where it's not affecting the subview shadow.

Comment: You should post more code. What is the feature you added? Where is this code being called?

Comment: @beyowulf - Code added

Comment: @Sidetalker - If you look, I've added more code. You'll see I just added an explicit statement in the viewDidLoad on one of the buttons, trying to disable the shadows. Didn't work. Mask to bounds is supposed to be true, right?

Comment: @DaveG Sorry, I misunderstood and thought the text on the buttons was the textField - yes, masksToBounds should be true and should be preventing the shadow as well.

Comment: It seems like the shadow's are appearing in a viewDidAppear, as there's a delay between the view's appearance and the shadows' appearance. So preventing the shadow in viewDidLoad is being superseded. It also seems like this view controller is a child view controller of an other view controller. Is there code related to shadow's there?

Comment: @beyowulf - Just removed the parent/super viewDidLoad call as it wasn't necessary anyway, didn't fix it. I also don't have any code running in the viewDidAppear so there's nothing for me to tweak or play with. I just tried setting the textfield to be first responder and of course the user never sees the shadow because clicking the text-box makes it go away permanently. This is crazy.

Comment: Calling super.viewDidLoad() does not call the parent view controller's viewDidLoad it calls the superclass's viewDidLoad (i.e. UIViewController). It is good practice to call the super function of any class function you override (e.g. viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidLayoutSubviews, etc.). My point was more that you're only considering the lifecycle of the child view controller, but there is more than one view controller on the screen.

Comment: Do you add ANY shadows somewhere in your code?

Comment: Nope, no image/button or any other object in my entire app has shadows added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thoroughly declaring that I didn't want shadow in every way I could:

```
//Rounded Rectangles
func roundBut (Type: UIView) {
    Type.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
    Type.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
    Type.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    Type.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
    Type.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
    Type.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
    Type.layer.masksToBounds = false
    Type.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
}
```

I finally decided to ask the question "if the shadow is appearing when I tell it not to, what happens when I tell it to appear?" I changed the code to:

```
//Rounded Rectangles
func roundBut (Type: UIView) {
    Type.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    Type.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(500, 500)
    Type.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    Type.layer.shadowRadius = 150.0
    Type.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
    Type.layer.masksToBounds = false
    Type.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    Type.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 127/255.0, green: 127/255.0, blue: 127/255.0, alpha: 0.10).CGColor
}
```

Solved, for now at least. I'll have to keep an eye on it in case it's a glitch that gets fixed.

I'm not sure why this solved my question. Fiddling around with it, the border being 1.0 or above and not a clear color was the code that seemed to make the shadow go away.If you have any thoughts please share them.